# Using composite keys for table joins in QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3

How to define two fields for join tables in QGIS3?

Screenshot of the option layer properties >> Joins:

[image: Layer properties Joins]

Today, in the layer properties >> Joins option, you can only add one field for reference in tables/layer.

Comment: In the english GUI it's *Joins*, not *union*. It edited this for better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Simply answered. It is **not possible** to use composite keys in layer *joins*, only in *relations* from QGIS 3.10 onwards (Project > Properties... > Relations):

[image]

But you could raise a feature request for this in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

A possible workaround is to create new (virtual) fields for each of your tables using *field calculator* containing suitable compositions of your two (or more) fields that define your composite keys. Then use these new fields to create your layer join.